# Why is a long string throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception in ColdFusion 8?

Tags: arrays, loops, coldfusion, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a function that returns a string value built from static text and passed arguments:

```
<cffunction name="additionalText" access="private" returntype="String"
    hint="Adds additional text around the field value for certain dataTypes.">
    <cfargument name="type" type="String" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="val" type="String" required="true" />

    <cfscript>
        var text = ARGUMENTS.val;

        if (ARGUMENTS.type == "A")
            text = ARGUMENTS.val & "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ";            
        else if (ARGUMENTS.type == "B")
            text = ARGUMENTS.val & "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum molestie pretium sodales. Aliquam neque eros, aliquet nec tincidunt rutrum, commodo sit amet enim. Pellentesque habitant";
        // Bad one - causing errors
        else if (ARGUMENTS.type == "C")
            text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum molestie pretium sodales. Aliquam neque eros, aliquet nec tincidunt rutrum, commodo sit amet enim. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse vitae orci sed arcu semper convallis ut nec quam. Fusce viverra, turpis vestibulum congue tristique, arcu dolor feugiat orci, non vestibulum orci nisi non lorem. Donec et urna ligula. Sed vulputate lacinia orci, in consequat mauris tincidunt vel. Nam molestie rhoncus arcu, eget vestibulum neque commodo consequat. Nullam scelerisque condimentum nisi, et elementum quam sed. ";
        return text;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

The "bad" string has a length of 647. Any call to the function throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

When I shorten the string in question, the exception does not occur. I don't really have an option here - I need the full string to be available.

Why is this happening, and more importantly, what can I do to fix it?

UPDATE:

I just tried to call the function from a different location, and it works fine:

```
<cfscript>
    function getIt(type, val){
        return additionalText(type, val);
    }

    x.func = getIt;
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#x.func("A", "XXXX")#" />
```

Confusing now...

UPDATE:

Here is the full text of the ColdFusion exception with Robust Exception turned ON:

```
The web site you are accessing has experienced an unexpected error.
Please contact the website administrator. 

The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.  

Error Occurred While Processing Request  



Resources: 
Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are using the correct syntax. 
Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution to your problem. 


Browser   Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0) 
Remote Address   ....
Referrer   ....
Date/Time   07-Sep-11 12:43 PM 

Stack Trace (click to expand)  



java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

UPDATE:

Here is how I'm calling the function.... I have an array of "fields". Each "field" object in the array has several properties which are set elsewhere. One of these properties is "formatFunction". Some fields have a formatFunction value like "formatPhone" or "formatDate", which are the names of function in the field object:

Field.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="init" access="package" returntype="Field" output="false">
        <!--- Default format Function --->
        <cfset THIS.formatFunction = additionalText />

        <cfif THIS.name EQ "Date">
            <cfset THIS.formatFunction = formatDate />
        </cfif>
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="formatDate" access="private" returntype="String">
        <cfargument name="val" type="String" required="true" />

        <cfreturn DateFormat(ARGUMENTS.val, "dddd mmmm d, yyyy") />
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="additionalText" access="private" returntype="String"
        hint="Adds additional text around the field value for certain dataTypes.">
        <cfargument name="type" type="String" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="val" type="String" required="true" />

        <cfscript>
            var text = ARGUMENTS.val;

            if (ARGUMENTS.type == "A")
                text = ARGUMENTS.val & "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ";            
            else if (ARGUMENTS.type == "B")
                text = ARGUMENTS.val & "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum molestie pretium sodales. Aliquam neque eros, aliquet nec tincidunt rutrum, commodo sit amet enim. Pellentesque habitant";
            // Bad one - causing errors
            else if (ARGUMENTS.type == "C")
                text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum molestie pretium sodales. Aliquam neque eros, aliquet nec tincidunt rutrum, commodo sit amet enim. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse vitae orci sed arcu semper convallis ut nec quam. Fusce viverra, turpis vestibulum congue tristique, arcu dolor feugiat orci, non vestibulum orci nisi non lorem. Donec et urna ligula. Sed vulputate lacinia orci, in consequat mauris tincidunt vel. Nam molestie rhoncus arcu, eget vestibulum neque commodo consequat. Nullam scelerisque condimentum nisi, et elementum quam sed. ";
            return text;
        </cfscript>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

I looping over the array at certain points, calling the formatFunction for each "field":

```
for (i=1; i<=ArrayLen(THIS.aPDFFormFields); i=i+1) {
    field = THIS.aPDFFormFields[i];
    // get the value input in the FORM for the specified field
    val = Trim(FORM[field.formFieldName]);

    if (IsCustomFunction(field.formatFunction))
        val = field.formatFunction(field.type, val);
}
```

This works for all other fields (formatting phone numbers, dates, times, etc.). It only errors out when that one condition is included.

UPDATE:

This exception is actually being thrown from a different loop, where I'm attempting to populate a PDF Form with values:

```
<cfpdfform
    source="myPDF.pdf"
    action="populate"
    destination="newPDF.pdf"
    overwrite="yes"
    overwritedata="yes">
    <cfloop array="#THIS.aPDFFormFields#" index="field">
        <cfpdfformparam
            name="#field.name#"
            value="#getFormattedFieldValue(FORM, field)#" />
    </cfloop>
</cfpdfform>


<cffunction name="getFormattedFieldValue" returntype="string" output="false">
    <cfargument name="fieldValues" type="Struct" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="field" type="Field" required="true" />

    <cfscript>
        var fieldValue = "";

        if (StructKeyExists(ARGUMENTS.fieldValues, fieldname))
            fieldValue = ARGUMENTS.fieldValues[fieldName];

        if (IsCustomFunction(field.formatFunction))
            fieldValue = field.formatFunction(fieldValue);

        if (!Len(fieldValue))
            fieldValue = " ";

        return fieldValue;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Can't see how a CFLOOP over an Array would throw an ArrayOutofBounds Exception. I'm not referencing indices anywhere in this logic!

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? I ran this on my CF8 instance and didn't get errors with strings of any length, with all types. How are you calling the function?

Comment: It's not giving me a line number. The Stack Trace only says "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBounds". I just kept removing lines until I stopped getting the error.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace in your original post? You should also ensure you have robust exceptions turned on in the CF Admin so we can make sure we have all of the information.

Comment: I'll also have to see how you're calling the function to see if there is something going on there.

Comment: Ditto here - this works fine on my CF9, what is the actual value you are trying to assign to 'text' in your else if statement? Also - is this the actual code?? you say that a return string is 'built' from the argument, but the return value you have here is a replacment for the arg. I would have expected to see something like text = text&" some new string";

Comment: As Dan asked, please quit showing us what *does* work. Show us the funciton call that *doesn't* work. And post the stack trace.

Comment: Your update doesn't clarify anything or tell what's happening. So we need to see how the error occurs in its natural habitat (how are you calling it, what's the context around it), and the full StackTrace of the error. Also, check your examples. In your update, you're calling the arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: I get the feeling that the OP may be looping over these function calls (perhaps looping over an array?) and that that or something like it is the problem.

Comment: So, following on with what Sean and Jason said, and looking at your StackTrace (you were right, not very helpful) that function is probably not the root cause of the error. So... how are you calling this function? In what context is the operation taking place? Usually errors like this that have no line number end up being memory related (a process that consumes all memory, so CF doesn't know what to do when it runs out).

Comment: I updated the question to include the full example of how I am dynamically calling the function.

Comment: Can you wrap the entire loop in a try/catch and then dump #cfcatch# and see if it offers anymore information?

Comment: Adjusted my answer below to show a test demonstrating that your function is fine. Your error is definitely somewhere in the surrounding logic.

Answer (score 1):

An **ArrayIndexOutOfBounds** error occurs when you try to reference an array element that is outside of the boundaries of a defined array. For instance, you have an array with 5 elements and you ask for array element 7, you get the error.

Your function returns a string, I don't see how it can be the cause of the error. Whatever is calling that function is most likely the cause of the error.

Comment: Thanks, that's why I'm confused. I know what ArrayIndexOutOfBounds means. I've been debugging this line-by-line, and when I remove that line, the exception disappears. That's why I think it's the cause.

Comment: Try/Catch just gave me the same information as the Exception:
Message [empty string]  
StackTrace java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  
TagContext array [empty]  
Type java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

You need to start testing things in isolation to figure out what's going on. I ran the following test using your Field.cfc and didn't get any errors:

```
<cfset FORM.myFormField = RepeatString("*", 700) />

<cfset BaseObject = createObject("component", "Field") />
<cfset BaseObject.Name = "foo" />
<cfset BaseObject.Type = "C" />
<cfset BaseObject.formFieldName = "myFormField" />
<cfset BaseObject.init() />

<cfset aPDFFormFields = [] />
<cfloop from="1" to="500" index="i">
    <cfset ArrayAppend(aPDFFormFields, Duplicate(BaseObject)) />
</cfloop>

<cfscript>
for (i=1; i<=ArrayLen(aPDFFormFields); i=i+1) {
    field = aPDFFormFields[i];
    // get the value input in the FORM for the specified field
    val = Trim(FORM[field.formFieldName]);

    if (IsCustomFunction(field.formatFunction)){
        val = field.formatFunction(field.type, val);
        writeOutput(i & ': ' & val & '<br />');
    }
}
</cfscript>
```

As Jason suggested in the comments above, place a try/catch in there, and figure out which object in the array is causing the error, and see if it's perhaps missing some required information in order for things to work correctly. Break things down into digestible pieces, and you'll suss out the error.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the reason for this exception, as cryptic as it is, is that I was trying to set a PDF Form Checkbox field with that long string, and it could not accept the value. I have asked the PDF Admin to update the PDF accordingly, so that we can properly update it as needed.